# laravel whereJsonContains with operators

Tags: mysql, json, laravel

I have a json column named "experience".

It's an array of objects with a structure like this

```
[
  {
    ...
    "years": 1
  },
  {
    ...
    "years": 2
  }
]
```

**I want to get users where has expeirence year grater than or equal 2**

currently I am doing this

```
User::whereJsonContains('experience', ['years' => 2]);
```

**but this returns only users where has experince years equal 2**

I tried todo this but it didn't work

```
User::whereJsonContains('experience->years', '>=' , 2);
User::where('experience->years', '>=' , 2);
```

Is there anyway to achieve this in laravel or mysql?

Comment: So each user has an array of experience in a skill?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, no. Would a better solution not be to move the skills / years out to separate table(s) and associate them to the users through relationships?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, each user has array of skills

Answer (score 0):

**It is not a proper solution but it may help you.**

```
$users = \DB::table('users')->where(\DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(experience, "$[*].years")'), '>=', 2)->get();
```

Comment: where is the operator? could you please explain the query?

Comment: Check my full query. In the end, it's `>=`.

Comment: It will search for *the year in the experience column* which is *greater than or equal to 2 years*. for JSON_EXTRACT() you can refer to this doc. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract

Comment: Test this query and let me know the results.

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. I make another table for experience and it work me. Thanks for help.